# Problem with the integration of this piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I encounter a problem when I try to integrate the piecewise function defined in the following code:

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"];

(* Parameters of the problem*)

M = 1; (* Mass scale*)
A = M/4 ;(* Background Amplitude*)
a = A; (* Perturbation Amplitude*)
L = 0.1/M; (* Background Length scale*)
Lb = 30*L; (* Boundary distance*)
l = L/20; (* Perturbation Length scale*)
d = L/3; (* Spatial translation of the perturbation *)
tmax = 10*L; (* Maximal time*)
\[Kappa] = 3*M; (*Velociy field stiffness*)
\[Delta]\[Chi]0[x_] = 
 a/(1 + ((x - d)/l)^2) + 
  a/(1 + ((x + d)/l)^2); (* Initial perturbation profile*)

(* Construct an initial characteristic with the correct asymptotical \
behaviour *)   

f1[x_] = -\[Kappa]*
  x; (* Desired profile close to x=0 to create the caustic *)
f2[x_] = 1; (* Asymptotical profile *)
v[x_] = Piecewise[{
   {f1[x], -L < x < L}, 
   {f2[x], x < -Lb/2 ||  x > Lb/2},
   {Interpolation[{{{-Lb/2}, f2[-Lb/2], f2'[-Lb/2], f2''[-Lb/2], 
        f2'''[-Lb/2], f2''''[-Lb/2]}, {{-L}, f1[-L], f1'[-L]}}][
     x], -Lb/2 < x < -L},
   {Interpolation[{{{Lb/2}, f2[Lb/2], f2'[Lb/2]}, {{L}, f1[L], 
        f1'[L]}}][x], L < x < Lb/2}}];


(* Define the initial condition for the field *)

s[x_] = M^2*Sqrt[(2 - 2*(v[x])^2)/(3 - (v[x])^2)];
q[x_] = Integrate[s[x], x, 
   Assumptions -> -Lb < x < Lb]; (* Integrate the spatial derivative*)
```

The piecewise function is called v[x] and it is defined explicitly on the intervals: [-L,L] ; ]-inf, Lb/2] and [Lb/2, +inf[ 
and defined as an interpolation on the remaining intervals.
Then I define s[x] by using this piecewise function v[x].
When I try to define a function q[x] as the integral of s[x] , I have the following error:

```
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -2.99988.
```

I have read the documentation on this error but I don't manage to relate this to my problem. Can anybody help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you think you could reduce this into a minimal-working-example?

Comment: I think you mean `Integrate[s[x],{ x, -Lb , Lb}]` rather than `Integrate[s[x], x,  Assumptions -> -Lb < x < Lb]`

Comment: `Integrate[s[x],{x,-.1,.1}]` and `Integrate[s[x],{x,1.5,3}]` and `Integrate[s[x],{x,-3,-1.5}]` appear to work with the rest of your code unchanged, but anything which strays into your `Interpolation` zones fails. Does that give you any ideas what to start looking at? Defining `q[x_]` and then using x as a variable of integration worries me.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : if you ignore the definition of the parameters, the example is really short. Please read from (* Construct an initial characteristic with the correct asymptotical \
behaviour *)

Comment: @andre Actually I want to define the function q[x] as an undefined integral but with  [-Lb,Lb] as domains

Comment: @Bill Thank you, it is very interesting indeed but why does the integration fail at the point x =  -2.99988 which is not in the interpolation domain?

Comment: It is perhaps failing at x= -2.99988 because Interpolation is doing some "probing" to establish the interpolation curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) to compute a numerical antiderivative:

```
q1 = NDSolveValue[{qq'[x] == s[x], qq[-Lb] == 0}, qq, {x, -Lb, Lb}]
(* Some extrapolation warnings that are due to how NDSolve rewrites Piecewise[].
   They are unimportant. *)

ListLinePlot@q0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since the interpolations are between just two points, one can use [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) for slightly better results.  (The OP's `Interpolation` leads to some small imaginary parts, due to a square-root of slightly negative numbers.  For some reason, we don't get that with the `InterpolatingPolynomial`.  The negative numbers are due to an overshoot around `x == 1.5` (try `1 - (v[-1.5 + 10^-6])^2`).

```
v1[x_] = Piecewise[{{f1[x], -L < x < L},
      {f2[x], x < -Lb/2 || x > Lb/2},
     {InterpolatingPolynomial[
      {{{-Lb/2}, f2[-Lb/2], f2'[-Lb/2], f2''[-Lb/2], f2'''[-Lb/2],
       f2''''[-Lb/2]}, {{-L}, f1[-L], f1'[-L]}}, x],
      -Lb/2 < x < -L},
    {InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{Lb/2}, f2[Lb/2], f2'[Lb/2]}, {{L}, f1[L], f1'[L]}}, x],
     L < x < Lb/2}}];

Block[{v = v1},
 q2 = NDSolveValue[{qq'[x] == s[x], qq[-Lb] == 0}, qq, {x, -Lb, Lb}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, MMA can't do Integration of squared interpolation functions.

Generate a new interpolationfunction of the squared function values.

```
Plot[(v[x])^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
s2 = Interpolation[
       Table[{x, M^2*Sqrt[(2 - 2*(v[x])^2)/(3 - (v[x])^2)]}, {x, -3, 3, 
              1/10}]];

Plot[s2[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
is2[x_] = Integrate[s2[x], x]

Plot[is2[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]